# SQL - How can I combine Select Statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

Is there any way to apply `Logical Operator -> OR` between 2 Select statements?

I am open to another other solutions which `satisfies above OR Condition`.

`If there is no data in 1st Select then goto next Select`

Example

```
SELECT column1, column2
  FROM table-name1 JOIN table-name2 
    ON column-name1 = column-name2
 WHERE //all condition
```

**OR**

```
SELECT column3, column4
  FROM table-name3 JOIN table-name4 
    ON column-name3 = column-name4
 WHERE //all condition
```

**Condition 1/ Query 1**

```
async getData() {
        try {
            const data = await this._conn.query(`

select first_name.value_name,quiz_table.answer, windows,player,first_name.value_id,country_place,current_name, pet_name, marker, relations
from schema_name.plugin,schema_name.quiz_table,schema_name.first_name, schema_name.value_version, schema_name.relationss
where plugin.answer= quiz_table.answer
and quiz_table.windows=first_name.value_id
and marker is not null
and schema_name.value_version.value_id= schema_name.first_name.value_id
and schema_name.value_version.caste= schema_name.first_name.caste
and schema_name.value_version.value_name= schema_name.first_name.value_name
and schema_name.value_version.version_number= schema_name.first_name.version_number
and schema_name.relationss.value_id= schema_name.first_name.value_id
and schema_name.relationss.caste= schema_name.first_name.caste
and schema_name.relationss.value_name= schema_name.first_name.value_name
and schema_name.relationss.version_number= schema_name.first_name.version_number
and  schema_name.quiz_table.windows= schema_name.first_name.value_id
and in_process='N'
}
```

**OR**

**Condition 2/ Query 2 - Display data**

```
select schema_name.relationss."relations", schema_name.quiz_table."answer", schema_name.quiz_table."windows", schema_name.quiz_table."in_process", schema_name.quiz_table."object_name", schema_name.quiz_table."processed_date", schema_name.quiz_table."player", schema_name.quiz_table."country_place", schema_name.tools."mesh_scope_note", schema_name.plugin."current_name", schema_name.plugin."pet_name"
            from schema_name.quiz_table, schema_name.tools, schema_name.plugin, schema_name.relationss, schema_name.value_version 
            where (in_process = 'N' 
              and schema_name.quiz_table."windows" = schema_name.tools."value_id"
              and schema_name.quiz_table."player" = schema_name.tools."language"
              and schema_name.quiz_table."answer" = schema_name.plugin."answer"
              and schema_name.relationss."language" = schema_name.quiz_table."player"
              and schema_name.relationss."language" = schema_name.tools."language"
              and schema_name.relationss."caste" = schema_name.tools."caste"
              and schema_name.relationss."value_name" = schema_name.tools."value_name"
              and schema_name.relationss."version_number" = schema_name.tools."version_number"
              and schema_name.relationss."value_id" = schema_name.tools."value_id"
              and schema_name.value_version."value_id" = schema_name.tools."value_id"
              and schema_name.value_version."version_number" = schema_name.tools."version_number"
              and schema_name.value_version."caste" = schema_name.tools."caste"
)
```

**NOTE**- In `WHERE` clause both Select has different conditions

Comment: Step 1) Switch to explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Nearly 30 years ago the syntax for `JOIN` keywords was adopted as a standard *(ANSI-92)*.  ***Stop*** using `,` to implicitly join tables, it's outdated by Three Decades.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show some sample data and desired results. And please consider supplying a [mcve] so we can help you better.

Comment: I made the changes

Comment: If *(as per your comment on an answer below)* the two queries have different columns, then you shouldn't be treating them as interposable, and certainly not trying to combine them in the way your question eludes to.  Instead, handle that in your programatic flow control.  It would be analogous to writing a function that sometimes returns an integer, and sometimes returns a dictionary.

Comment: Hi @MatBailie can you give more idea as to how I can approach? I am beginner to sql. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean by **Logical Operator -> OR between 2 Select statements**.  SQL is basically a set-processing language: Your two SELECT operations return dissimilar sets of rows. What does it mean, to you, to apply the OR operation to such dissimilar sets?  Please [edit] your question or ask another.

Comment: It's not a SQL problem.  The problem is that you're intending to treat two fundamentally different things as being the same thing.  You shouldn't do it.  Instead, keep them separate and write your code to handle that, such as with `IF` statements.

Comment: Thanks `If - else` should help solve this problem

Comment: Please do not edit a question to be fundamentally different from what it was initially.  It invalidates comments and answers, this creates confusion when people look back at the question in the future.  Instead, ask a new question to reflect your new needs.

Comment: Sure @MatBailie, I will post a new question

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is `union all` and `exists` -- well, assuming the two selects return the same column:

```
with cte as (
      select . . .
     )
select *
from cte
union all
select *
from t2
where not exists (select 1 from cte);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have mentioned in `NOTE` that both `SELECT has different conditions-> columns are different`

Comment: @AAama . . . Your question implies that the `where` clause is using different columns, not the `select`.  Actually, quite clearly.

Comment: I have add actual code, hope this helps. Thanks